# feature branch origin and local out of sync after rebase

Tags: git

I'm trying to follow the Git work-flow described here: http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/

After finishing one feature and merging it int to my development branch, I updated a different feature branch using git rebase.

This seemed to work fine, but now I tried to push new changes on this feature branch to its origin counter part and I get the following error:

```
! [rejected]        open-sea-dragon-feature -> open-sea-dragon-feature (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@bitbucket.org:jeffreycwitt/lombardpress2.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

My tree looks like this: [image]

In the picture you can see the two subsequent commits for the open-sea-dragon feature, after the rebase, were placed after the tip of the develop branch on my local machine. But this didn't happen for the origin counterpart and now they are out of sync.

I'm wondering how I can my feature branch back in sync with the origin feature branch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's exactly why you **should not rewrite the history of already-published branches**. You now have two options:

1. If you are *absolutely sure* that no one but you is working off your remote branch (i.e. `origin/open-sea-dragon-feature`), you can force-push your updated branch:

   ```
   git push --force origin open-sea-dragon-feature
   ```

   In your case, you will "lose" two commits during this procedure, but that should be alright here, because their rebased counterparts are included in the new branch.

   Again: **don't do this** if other people may have already pulled the remote branch! They will get into a boatload of trouble when suddenly pulling a rewritten history.
2. If you cannot force-push your updated branch (for reasons said above), you'll need to bite the bullet and merge the remote branch:

   ```
   git merge origin/open-sea-dragon-feature
   ```

   After that, you'll be able to push with a simple fast-forward merge and other collaborators that use the branch will be able to easily pull your changes.

   This will lead to some duplicate commits appearing in your history. Git *should* handle the differences though and be able to perform a clean merge. If the rebased commits are identical diff-wise, you should not get any conflicts while merging.

Comment: Ok, since I'm the only one working on it a force push should be fine. But to clarify for future reference: I guess I should not push to "origin" feature branches that I'm working on -- because I'll need to "rebase" these feature branches from time to time to stay in sync with the development branch (A slight bummer since I like being able to back up my work.)

Comment: @Jeff, just today I wrote an answer to [exactly that question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29767483/1995300) that you just asked. Personally, I think it's OK to rewrite the history of published branches that you *know* only you are working on (like for example a feature branch of an individual fork).